# Multiple SharedPreferences in an android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("user1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("firstName", firstnameString);
editor.commit();

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("user2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
...
```

I am trying to create multiple sharedpreferences using the above code and trying to access all the sharedpreference names i.e user1,user2 etc using the code below.

But i am getting a NULLPointerException while accessing even though the sharedpreference is created.

```
Map<String,?> allsharedpref = pref.getAll();
if(allsharedpref!=null){
    for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allsharedpref.entrySet()){
    Toast.makeText(this, entry.getKey()+"\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: where you are initializing `pref` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get values from all `SharedPreferences` which you have created. you will need to read file names from `shared_prefs` :

```
File prefsdir = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir,"shared_prefs");
String[] list = prefsdir.list();
String[] preflist = new String[list.length()];
for(int i=0;i<list.length(),i++){
  String preffile = list[i].substring(0, list[i].length()-4);
  preflist[i]=preffile;
}
```

Now use `preflist` to get values from all `SharedPreferences`:

```
for(int index=0;index<preflist.length(),index++){
  SharedPreferences spPref = getSharedPreferences(preflist[index], MODE_PRIVATE);
  Map<String,?> allsharedpref = spPref.getAll();
  if(allsharedpref!=null){
    for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allsharedpref.entrySet()){
    Toast.makeText(this, entry.getKey()+"\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSharedPreferences`() can only be called after `onCreate`() has been called on an Activity.